# Wait for all processes to finish python

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

This question has been asked numerous times, but I couldn't find an answer to match my specific set up.

I have a script which uses multiprocessing. Here is a much simplified example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def my_function(arg1,arg2):
     print(arg1,arg2)

with Pool(processes=5) as pool:
     pool.starmap(function, [(arg1,arg2),(arg1,arg2)])
     pool.join()

print("should only run once all processes are finished")
```

I would like the pool to close at this point and normal single processing functionality to continue. I thought the context manager would handle the closure of the pool, and the .join() would ensure that it only closes once all processes are finished. But I am seeing behaviour which suggests that the program is running beyond the context manager before all processes are finished. Is there more I need to do at this point?

Also, in this case there are 5 processes assigned, but only 2 tuples of args passed to the function. What do the surplus 3 processes do in this instance?

Python -V 3.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `pool.close()` before `pool.join()`.
and you can see which process running the function, by calling `_identity` variable of a current process. In the end, you can make sure that only the main process is running by calling the `name` of the current process.
since the number of calls is less than the number of processes, the rest of the processes are just doing the usual OS stuff.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process
def my_function(arg1,arg2):
    rank = f'running on process: {current_process()._identity[0]}'
    print(rank, arg1,arg2)


arg1 = 'arg1'
arg2 = 'arg2'
with Pool(processes=5) as pool:
    pool.starmap(my_function, [(arg1,arg2),(arg1,arg2)])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

print(current_process().name)
print("should only run once all processes are finished")
```

output:

```py
running on process: 1 arg1 arg2
running on process: 2 arg1 arg2
MainProcess
should only run once all processes are finished
```